# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x\sin\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}{x^{3}+n}\right)^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have a task to research $$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x\sin\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}{x^{3}+n}\right)^{2}$$ for uniform convergence on $0<x<+\infty$. I tried using Weierstrass M-test, but couldn't find the sequence. So what test should I use to prove uniform or non-uniform convergence of this series?

Comment: I assume what you mean is you are investigating the uniform convergence of the sequence (as $k\to\infty$) of functions $$f_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\left( \frac{x\sin\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}{x^3+n} \right)^2$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sup_{x \in (0, \infty)}\frac{x^2}{(x^3 +n)^2} = O\left(n^{-4/3} \right)$$

Comment: @Henrik: Since when are hints prohibited in lieu of complete answers? If so then this has never been applied consistently for even a tiny percentage of the time.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick.